# type-checking with immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

*Immutable.js* requires one to use its own syntax to avoid mutating objects — in practice always requiring a `setIn` / `updateIn` for depths greater than 1.

`setIn` / `updateIn` but also, even the simpler `get` and `set` methods cannot be *meaningfully* typed-checked at development time (e.g. with [FlowType](https://flowtype.org/)) as they simply use strings.

Is there a pattern that would allow one to statically type-check code using immutable.js or at least narrow the extent of code where this unsafe string-based getting and setting occurs? Otherwise it would seem that for a performance benefit (or the convenience of using strict equality tests) one is giving up static type checking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you care so much about type safety that you're willing to completely change the way you code, why not simply use a typed language and transpile?

Comment: that's why I am using FlowType as I'd rather stay in JavaScript land. Plus, I think even using a transpiled language presents exactly the same problem with immutable.js.

Comment: With a strongly typed language you probably don't need Immutable.js, simply use immutable types native to the language you're using and let the transpiler / compiler do the heavy lifting... but that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Even if I agree that Javascript is not ideal for this, I would still like to see the answer – sometimes leaving JS is just not an option, e.g. in existing project.

Comment: I frequently have this discussion at work, I don't think that making sure you have the EXACT keys inside a generic map is in the realm of type checking. Type checking will tell you that you have a map with keys of type 'string' (for example) and values of List<number>. Even in say Java, you aren't able to use types to say, these are the named keys in a map. If you want that feature, use either 1) a Record, 2) some class/object/wrapper of your own creating that's more specific than a Map.

Comment: Futhermore, you can absolutely get type level adherence with Flow. You can say this is a Map<string, string> and if you try to access with a number, boolean (non-string, you will be warned)

Comment: @rooftop in Java you'd create an enum to use as keys in your `Map<SomeEnum, SomeValue>`, you wouldn't actually use `Map<String, String>`, so yes, you'd have the compiler check that you are actually using meaningful keys. `Immutable.js` is a library and so it can't possibly anticipate and enumerate the keys that the client programmers would want to use, hence this conundrum.

Comment: Fair point about the Enum, pretty sure you can say `Map<'key1' | 'key2', string>` to get enum like behavior.

Comment: [this example](https://coderwall.com/p/vxk_tg/using-immutable-js-in-typescript) of someone dealing with this in TypeScript might help. Why would you deliverately make a programming language more complex? JavaScript doesn't have types, and it doesn't need them, and it's a better and more powerfull language because of that.